# Decay of total Progeny of subcritical Galton-Watson Tree

Tags: probability, inequality

Consider a Galton-Watson tree with offspring distribution $\xi_i^n\sim\nu$. Let $Z_0 = 1$ and $Z_{i+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{Z_i}\xi_k^{i+1}$. Finally the total progeny of our Galton-Watson tree is $S:=\sum_{i=0}^\infty Z_i$. Assuming that $\mathbb{E}[\xi_i^n]<1$ can we show
$$
\mathbb{P}[S\geq n]\leq Ce^{-cn}?
$$
If not what other assumptions would we need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***To answer the question** you need to put some restrictions on the moments of $\xi_i^n$ or equivalently the tails of its mass function. At the moment it is not even possible to say anything about the simpler quantity $\mathbb{P} \left ( \xi_i^n > n \right )$ so naturally nothing can be said about $\mathbb{P} \left ( S > n \right )$.*

---

A typical approach for obtaining exponential concentration bounds is the Cramer-Chernof method. Putting $M_S \left ( \theta \right ) = \mathbb{E} \left [ e^{\theta S} \right ]$ for any $\theta$ using Markov's inequality we have that:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \left ( S > n \right ) \leq M_S \left ( \theta \right ) e^{-n \theta}
\end{equation}

For concreteness say $\mathbb{E} \left [ \xi_i^n \right ] = m < 1$ and that $\xi_i^n$ has generating function $G_\xi \left ( s \right ) = \mathbb{E} \left [ s^{\xi_i^n} \right ]$. Then from [Feller](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/An+Introduction+to+Probability+Theory+and+Its+Applications%2C+Volume+2%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471257097) we know that $S$ has generating function

\begin{equation}
G_S \left ( s \right ) = s \times G_\xi \left ( G_S \left ( s \right ) \right ) 
\end{equation}

I'll treat the simplest Galton-Watson process where $\xi_i^n \sim \text{Poisson} \left ( m \right ) $. However the approach can be used other specific choices of $\nu$ and the final result holds whenever $\mathbb{P} \left ( \xi_i^n = k \right ) \leq \frac{m^ke^-k}{k!}$ for any $k$. Putting $s = e^\theta$ and recalling the generating function of a Poisson distribution we have:

\begin{equation}
M_S \left ( \theta \right ) = e^\theta \times e^{m \left [ M_S \left ( \theta \right ) - 1  \right ]}
\end{equation}

Putting $W$ for [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) we further have that:

\begin{align}
& M_S \left ( \theta \right ) = e^{\theta - m} e^{m M_S \left ( \theta \right )} \\ 
& \Leftrightarrow  - m M_S \left ( \theta \right ) e^{-m M_S \left ( \theta \right )} = -m e^{\theta - m} \\ 
& \Leftrightarrow - m M_S \left ( \theta \right ) = W \left ( -m e^{\theta - m}  \right ) \\ 
& \Leftrightarrow M_S \left ( \theta \right ) = -\frac{1}{m} W \left ( -m e^{\theta - m}  \right )
\end{align}

The final line is valid as long as the argument of the $W$ function is larger than or equal to $-e^{-1}$. Put:

\begin{equation}
\bar{\theta} = m + \log \left ( \frac{1}{m} \right ) - 1
\end{equation}

Substituting into the previous line we have:

\begin{equation}
M_S \left ( \bar{\theta} \right ) = -\frac{1}{m} W \left ( -e^{-1} \right ) = \frac{1}{m}
\end{equation}

Finally substituting into the original Cramer-Chernof bound we obtain the desired exponential decay:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \left ( S > n \right ) \leq \frac{1}{m} e^{-n \left [ m + \log \left ( \frac{1}{m} \right ) - 1 \right ]}
\end{equation}